# Call REST API with and without user context

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, microservices, access-token

I have a user microservice. This microservice uses `token authorization`. Now it's consumed by web application. Workflow looks like this:

- user logs in to web application using `AzureAd OpenIdConnect`;
- web application receives `access token` (`authorization code` flow);
- web application gets user details from user service passing `access token` in HTTP request header.

Also I have a daemon microservice where I don't have a user context. I want to allow this daemon service to get user details from user service too. I'm going to use `client credentials` flow for that case.

How to organize user service rest api properly?

I'm thinking about this approach:

- user's data is available at this URL `/users/{userId}/info`;
- applications with user context (i.e. access token is issued for particular user using `authorization code` flow) can consume data only for `current user` or `current user` is an admin and can work with another user's data;
- daemon applications without `current user` (i.e. access token is issued for the application itself using `client credentials` flow) can read data for any user.

What is the best practices for such cases?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best and more restful approach to define this API is to build a unique endpoint `/users/{id}`.
Where id can be an actual real user id or a predefined value like 'me'. It is the user service the one who has to retrieve from the token the user information in case that the id value is 'me'.
The other changes that I would make is to use `users` instead of `user` because rest good practices say that the elements in the URL are **collection**.
And the last one, to not use `info` because it is redundant. Because when you query for an entity obviously you want its info